# SSH port 22 connection refused

Tags: macos, ssh

I just bought a brand new Mac mini to use as a server. SSH over the same local network works fine. I can run `ssh myusername@192.xxx.xxx.x` and it works--I can enter the server and create, modify, delete files etc. I have setup my ssh keys as well, and do not need to enter my password to login. It all works fine.

However, when I try to connect when on a different network, I get `port 22: Connection refused`.

Here is what I have already tried **on my Mac mini server**:

- System Preferences -> Sharing -> Remote Login -> Turn on. Check YES for "Allow access for all users" and for "Allow full disk access for remote users"
- `sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist`
- System Preferences - Security -> Firewall -> Turned firewall OFF.

I opened `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/ssh.plist` file and I saw it has a plist key:
`Disabled`, with value `true`. However I tried opening and editing this file, and it was locked. I tried unlocking and it still would not allow me to save it. I then tried to edit it using `sudo nano` in Terminal, and I was also refused saving changes as well.

What else can I try to see if port 22 is listening? or force it to listen? thanks.